# How to correcntly sort time values in a diagram in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, diagram

I am a beginner in Python and to start of I want to make some simple data visualizations.

To be precise I would like to plot a diagram with the runtimes of movies.

Here's how my code is looking right now:

```
# import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# movie names
x=['titanic','ironman','avengers','sholay','thor','caption america','dabang','bajarangi bhaijaan']
# movie runtime
y=['2:32:23','2:23:5','2:6:45','3:10:23','2:3:23','1:23:5','2:16:42','2:10:23']

# use scatter plot for better visualisation
plt.scatter(x,y,marker='*',s=200,color='r')

# use this if you want to show in bar graph 
#plt.bar(x,y,color='r')

plt.xlabel('movie_name',color='c')
plt.ylabel('movie_runtime',color='c')

# make grid
plt.grid(True,color='y')

# use for better show /tilt x axis values / movies names
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

# show out graph
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

The problem is now in the plot, the time values aren't sorted properly.
The shortest movie isn't the lowest on the y-axis, instead it's just the first movie in the list that is the lowest. How can I change this?

Comment: Use a proper datatype for the time instead of string?

Answer (score 1):

For example by converting the string to [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) (assuming no movie is longer than 23h, 59m and 59s) and setting a [formatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html) for it:

```py
from datetime import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

x=['titanic','ironman','avengers','sholay','thor','caption america','dabang','bajarangi bhaijaan']
y=['2:32:23','2:23:5','2:6:45','3:10:23','2:3:23','1:23:5','2:16:42','2:10:23']

# to datetime data type
y=[datetime.strptime(t, "%H:%M:%S") for t in y]

plt.scatter(x,y,marker='*',s=200,color='r')

plt.xlabel('movie_name',color='c')
plt.ylabel('movie_runtime',color='c')

# set y-axis / time formatter
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S"))

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.grid(True, color='y')

plt.show()
```

[image]